# Комплексное условие отбора

Tags: sql, sql-server

#### Задача:

У нас есть ФизЛица у которых есть кадровая история 
В кадровой истории хранятся места работы, дата устройства и увольнения и тип трудоустройства
Типов всего 2: **"Основное"** и **"Совмещение"**

**Нам необходимо получить текущее т.е. где дата увольнения пустая и оно либо основное, либо совмещение**
Но так же у нас есть ситуации, с 2-мя текущими местами работы (это 2 записи в таблице для одного физЛица), как правило 1-е Основное и 2-е Совмещение

**Всего у нас 3 случая: Основное, Основное и Совмещение (2 записи в таблице) и только Совмещение**

В первых 2 случаях нам нужно только основное, а в последнем разумеется берем совмещение

#### Проблема

У меня не выходит получить только основное трудоустройство во 2-ом случае, он получает 2 записи и получается дубликат, который нам не нужен

По сути условие звучит так: Получать текущее Основное трудоустройство, но если его нету, то Совмещение.
У нас всегда должно быть только одно физлицо с одним трудоустройством

Ниже вырезка из кода с самим условием

```
  FROM [ELMA3].[dbo].[FizicheskieLica] as fz
  INNER JOIN FizicheskieLica_KadrovayaIst AS kadr ON kadr.Parent = fz.Id 
  AND ((kadr.TipTrudoustroystva = 'Основное') AND (kadr.TipTrudoustroystva <> 'совмещение')) 
  OR ((kadr.TipTrudoustroystva <> 'Основное') AND (kadr.TipTrudoustroystva = 'совмещение'))
  AND (kadr.DataUvoljneniya >= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) OR kadr.DataUvoljneniya is null)
```

Есть идея реализовать XOR, но я не знаю как это сделать и насколько он тут подойдет
Возможно вы знаете как тут можно вы уже сталкивались с подобной ситуацией и знаете подходящие инструменты

Comment: Надо просто в CTE нумеровать строки `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY fz.Id ORDER BY CASE WHEN kadr.TipTrudoustroystva = 'Основное' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)`, а в основном запросе брать строку с номером 1. Если у человека одна строка - её номер будет 1, если две - 1 будет у строки с основной работой.

Comment: Альтернативно - можно для неосновной работы проверить WHERE NOT EXISTS строки с основной работой для того же работника (или просто ещё одной строки).

Comment: @Akina проверить не смогу сегодня, напишите решение, завтра протестирую обязательно оставлю обратную связь + я не совсем понимаю в каком контексте указать выражение выше и последнее тоже пока как конкретно реализовать не знаю т.к. не на рабочем месте, но большое спасибо за идею